# How to find lines with current date with %d-%h-%Y format assigned to a variable in all files

Tags: shell, unix

I have a directory under which i have many access files like:

```
access
access87681
access98709
```

Now i am trying grep all those lines with current date in format `+%d-%h-%Y`.

I have written like below:

```
tm1=$(date '+%d-%h-%Y')
sed -n '/$tm1/p' $dir/access* > $loc/OUD_Req_Res_matrix_data
```

I am trying to grep all `$dir/access*` files with `$tm1` which is current date in above date format and pushing them into output file `$loc/OUD_Req_Res_matrix_data`.

the above code is not working. Please suggest

Comment: The reason i am trying to put a date format is because the access files have date format in below format:

[24/Jan/2019:13:13:03 +0000] MODIFY REQ 

and i need to grep all those lines with current date from all access file into one output file

Comment: If you use single quotes variables aren't interpolated. Maybe you wanted double quotes? `... sed -n "/$tm1/p" ...`

Comment: I have writte like below:

tm1=$(date '+%d-%h-%Y')

dir=/u02/private/oracle/config/instances/oud-server-instance1/OUD/logs

loc=/u02/monitoring/scripts

sed -n "/$tm1/p" $dir/access* > $loc/OUD_Req_Res_matrix_data
===============================
ouput:---- there is a 0kb OUD_Req_Res_matrix_data file created. No data

Comment: if i am doing sed -n '\:23/Jan/2019:p' access* > tmp =========> this works but i will be required to put this into script hence the date will be keep on changing that's why i am assigning the date in particular format in one variable

Answer (score 0):

With `tm1=$(date '+%d-%h-%Y')` and access-files without spaces, you can use:

```
sed -n "/${tm1}/p" $dir/access*
```

When the date has slashes, the `sed` command would break.
You can escape the slashes with

```
sed 's#/#\\/#g' <<< "$tm1"
```

Use this in your command:

```
sed -n "/$(sed 's#/#\\/#g' <<< "$tm1")/p" $dir/access*
```

Comment: While doing the above command like:

sed -n "/$(sed 's#/#\\/#g' <<< "$tm1")/p" access* | wc -l

it is returning 0 line while access logs does have many lines with current date
in below format:
%d-%h-%Y

Comment: Can you try `sed -n "/${tm1}/p" $dir/access*` (your date format is without slashes) ?

Comment: sed -n '\:23/Jan/2019:p' access* > tmp            ---------------------  This works for me however as i will be required to schedule, the current date will keep on changing. The above command doesn't give me any output

Comment: Can you try `tm1="/23\/Jan\/2019"` and `sed -n "${tm1}/p" access > tmp` ?
When this works, try `tm1=$(date '+your_format_string' | sed 's#/#\\/#g' )`